# Which is the best way to load a string (HTML code) in TWebBrowser?

Tags: delphi, internet-explorer, delphi-xe7, twebbrowser

I have a string var 'HTMLCode' that contains HTML code. I want to load this code into the browser.

This is Embarcadero's code:

```
procedure THTMLEdit.EditText(CONST HTMLCode: string);
{VAR
   Doc: IHTMLDocument2;
   TempFile: string; }
begin
 TempFile := GetTempFile('.html');  
 StringToFile(TempFile, HTMLCode);
 wbBrowser.Navigate(TempFile);

 Doc := GetDocument;
 if Doc <> NIL
 then Doc.Body.SetAttribute('contentEditable', 'true', 0);  //crash here when I load complex html files

 DeleteFile(TempFile);
end;
```

It has some [problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39745849/how-stop-twebbrowser-from-adding-file-in-front-of-my-links?noredirect=1#comment66824665_39745849) so I replaced it with this one:

```
procedure THTMLEdit.EditText(CONST HTMLCode: string);
VAR
   TSL: TStringList;
   MemStream: TMemoryStream;
begin
 wbBrowser.Navigate('about:blank');
 WHILE wbBrowser.ReadyState < READYSTATE_INTERACTIVE
  DO Application.ProcessMessages;

 GetDocument.DesignMode := 'On';

 if Assigned(wbBrowser.Document) then
  begin
    TSL := TStringList.Create;
    TRY
      MemStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
      TRY
        TSL.Text := HTMLCode;
        TSL.SaveToStream(MemStream);
        MemStream.Seek(0, 0);
        (wbBrowser.Document as IPersistStreamInit).Load(TStreamAdapter.Create(MemStream));
      FINALLY
        MemStream.Free;
      end;
    FINALLY
      TSL.Free;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

But this one has problems also . First, when I insert links (...) into the HTML code, the browser will alter the code, [appending](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39745849/how-stop-twebbrowser-from-adding-file-in-front-of-my-links?noredirect=1#comment66824665_39745849) 'about:' in front of my URLs. Second: it is slower than the first procedure (the one with temp file).

Can I load HTML code in browser without navigating first to 'about:blank'?

Comment: source: http://www.swissdelphicenter.ch/en/showcode.php?id=1096

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You could load your `HTML` code as the below

```
procedure THTMLEdit.EditText(CONST HTMLCode: string);
var
  Doc: Variant;
begin
  if NOT Assigned(wbBrowser.Document) then
    wbBrowser.Navigate('about:blank');

  Doc := wbBrowser.Document;
  Doc.Clear;
  Doc.Write(HTMLCode);
  Doc.Close;
end;
```

Comment: It works - after adding  Doc.DesignMode := 'On' to your code :) Many thanks. However, it still shows the 'about:' problem when I INSERT html link in it. Details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39745849/how-stop-twebbrowser-from-adding-file-in-front-of-my-links?noredirect=1#comment66853179_39745849

Comment: @Silvester You need to include `<base href=...>` tag in the `HTML` links.

Comment: nope: I entered '<head><base href="c:\My web site\" target="_blank"></head>' and the link after that was changed to: <A href="file:///c:/My%20web%20site/MyFile.html">Link</A>

Comment: Follow up question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41957051/how-to-change-font-in-twebbrowser

Comment: This only works for VCL and NOT FMX, because the document property does not exist in FMX!

Comment: @GregT in FMX, there is [TWebBrowser.LoadFromStrings](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Athens/en/FMX.WebBrowser.TCustomWebBrowser.LoadFromStrings).

Answer (score 9):

**Your Questions:**

- First, when I insert links (...) into the HTML code, the browser will alter the code, appending 'about:' in front of my URLs.
- Second: it is slower than the first procedure (the one with temp file).
- Can I load HTML code in browser without **navigating first to 'about:blank**'?

**Answers:**

- Yes it's possible without change to the link!
- No, it is not slower!
- Yes, it is possible, no need to Navigate first to **about:blank**

We start with code and the first procedure (only to show where the about: ...  comes from).

```
{$R *.DFM}
var
Doc: IHTMLDocument2;
TempFile: string;
xBody   : IHTMLElement;
xLoaded : Boolean;
onlyOnce: Boolean;

procedure TForm1.WB_LoadHTML(HTMLCode: string);
var
  sl: TStringList;
  ms: TMemoryStream;
begin
  xLoaded := False;
  WebBrowser.Navigate('about:blank');
  while WebBrowser.ReadyState < READYSTATE_INTERACTIVE do
   Application.ProcessMessages;

  if Assigned(WebBrowser.Document) then
  begin
    sl := TStringList.Create;
    try
      ms := TMemoryStream.Create;
      try
        sl.Text := HTMLCode;
        sl.SaveToStream(ms);
        ms.Seek(0, 0);
        (WebBrowser.Document as IPersistStreamInit).Load(TStreamAdapter.Create(ms));
      finally
        ms.Free;
      end;
    finally
      sl.Free;
      Doc :=  WebBrowser.Document as IHTMLDocument2;
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.LoadHTMLBtnClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
WB_LoadHTML(Memo1.Text);
end;

procedure TForm1.LoadFileBtnClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
Memo1.Lines.LoadFromFile('G:\Programme\Apache Group\Apache\htdocs\bearbeiten1.html');
end;
```

We have created 2 files (which are identical) only script differs to get an alert at load.
**bearbeiten1.html**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
alert ("bearbeiten1.html");      
</script>
```

**bearbeiten3.html**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
alert ("bearbeiten3.html");      
</script>
```

With click on *Load File* we load the "bearbeiten1.html" file
and with *WB_LoadHTML* we load it into Memory.

we get **URL : about:blank**

[image]

and the alert

[image]

now we create a link:
we select the blue part and click *createlink*

[image]

The link is created

[image]

and also the new "Doc.body.innerHTML"

```
procedure TForm1.createlinkBtnClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
Doc.execCommand('createlink', false,'bearbeiten3.html');
Memo1.Text := Doc.body.innerHTML;
end;
```

[image]

So far so good! But will it work...? **No**

After a click on the link all we get is a blank site with URL:

[image]

Now we try the new *EditText()* code

```
procedure TForm1.EditText(CONST HTMLPath: string);
begin
 TempFile := HTMLPath;
 xLoaded := False;
 WebBrowser.Navigate(TempFile);
 Doc :=  WebBrowser.Document as IHTMLDocument2;
 if Doc <> nil then  xLoaded := True;
end;

procedure TForm1.EditTextBtnClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  EditText('G:\Programme\Apache Group\Apache\htdocs\bearbeiten1.html');
end;
```

With click on Load File we load the "bearbeiten1.html" file again
and with EditTextBtnClick we load it direct.
Looks much better! Will it work ...?

[image]

Let's click the link - we get the alert!! From number ...3.html"

[image]

and the .html file is loaded without problem.

[image]

**To your other problem**

```
 if Doc <> NIL
then Doc.Body.SetAttribute('contentEditable', 'true', 0);
//crash here when I load complex html files
```

You did it in the wrong place, as the **body** is only available after the site is loaded!!

So I put it in the event *WebBrowserNavigateComplete2*

Only a fast solution can be improved

```
procedure TForm1.WebBrowserNavigateComplete2(Sender: TObject;
  const pDisp: IDispatch; var URL: OleVariant);
begin
if xLoaded  = True then begin
    xBody := Doc.Get_body;
    if xBody <> nil then begin
       xBody.SetAttribute('contentEditable', 'true', 0);
       Memo1.Text := Doc.body.innerHTML;
       xLoaded := False;
    end;
end;
label2.Caption := URL;
end;
```

**The complete code.**

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    WebBrowser: TWebBrowser;
    Label1: TLabel;
    Label2: TLabel;
    Memo1: TMemo;
    LoadHTMLBtn: TButton;
    LoadFileBtn: TButton;
    EditTextBtn: TButton;
    createlinkBtn: TButton;
    innerHTMLBtn: TButton;
    procedure LoadHTMLBtnClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure LoadFileBtnClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure EditTextBtnClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure createlinkBtnClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure WebBrowserNavigateComplete2(Sender: TObject;
      const pDisp: IDispatch; var URL: OleVariant);
    procedure innerHTMLBtnClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    procedure WB_LoadHTML(HTMLCode: string);
    procedure EditText(CONST HTMLPath: string);
  public
    { Public-Deklarationen }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.DFM}
var
Doc: IHTMLDocument2;
TempFile: string;
xBody   : IHTMLElement;
xLoaded : Boolean;
onlyOnce: Boolean;

procedure TForm1.WB_LoadHTML(HTMLCode: string);
var
  sl: TStringList;
  ms: TMemoryStream;
begin
  xLoaded := False;
  WebBrowser.Navigate('about:blank');
  while WebBrowser.ReadyState < READYSTATE_INTERACTIVE do
   Application.ProcessMessages;

  if Assigned(WebBrowser.Document) then
  begin
    sl := TStringList.Create;
    try
      ms := TMemoryStream.Create;
      try
        sl.Text := HTMLCode;
        sl.SaveToStream(ms);
        ms.Seek(0, 0);
        (WebBrowser.Document as IPersistStreamInit).Load(TStreamAdapter.Create(ms));
      finally
        ms.Free;
      end;
    finally
      sl.Free;
      Doc :=  WebBrowser.Document as IHTMLDocument2;
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.LoadHTMLBtnClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
WB_LoadHTML(Memo1.Text);
end;

procedure TForm1.LoadFileBtnClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
Memo1.Lines.LoadFromFile('G:\Programme\Apache Group\Apache\htdocs\bearbeiten1.html');
end;

procedure TForm1.EditText(CONST HTMLPath: string);
begin
 TempFile := HTMLPath;
 xLoaded  := False;
 WebBrowser.Navigate(TempFile);
 if onlyOnce then WebBrowser.Navigate(TempFile);
 onlyOnce := False;
 Doc :=  WebBrowser.Document as IHTMLDocument2;
 if Doc <> nil then  xLoaded := True;
end;

procedure TForm1.EditTextBtnClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  EditText('G:\Programme\Apache Group\Apache\htdocs\bearbeiten1.html');
end;

procedure TForm1.createlinkBtnClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
Doc.execCommand('createlink', false,'bearbeiten3.html');
Memo1.Text := Doc.body.innerHTML;
end;

procedure TForm1.WebBrowserNavigateComplete2(Sender: TObject;
  const pDisp: IDispatch; var URL: OleVariant);
begin
if xLoaded then begin
    xBody := Doc.Get_body;
    if xBody <> nil then begin
       xBody.SetAttribute('contentEditable', 'true', 0);
       Memo1.Text := Doc.body.innerHTML;
       xLoaded := False;
    end;
end;
label2.Caption := URL;
end;

procedure TForm1.innerHTMLBtnClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
Memo1.Text := Doc.body.innerHTML;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
 onlyOnce := True;
end;
end.
```

**UPDATE:**
I forgot to set the Tempfile Path in the code (copy paste error).
Also FormCreate added.
and only one time load the TempFile twice! (see code)

**Important** in the *head* tag of the TempFile must be a **link**

bearbeiten1.html same as bearbeiten3.html only `alert ("bearbeiten3.html");` must be adapted!!

**bearbeiten1.html**

```
<head>
<link href="file:///G:\Programme\Apache Group\Apache\htdocs\maor.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
</head>
<body leftmargin="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" topmargin="0" bgcolor="#1F2E53">
<script type="text/javascript">
  alert ("bearbeiten1.html");        
</script>
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" >
      <tr height="211">
        <td width="2%" height="211"></td>
        <td valign="top" width="36%" height="211">
            <table width="448" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
             <tr height="21">
                <td width="8" height="21"></td>
                <td class="FormControlrechts" width="150" height="21"></td>
                <td width="23" height="21"></td>
                <td class="FormControl" width="213" height="21">
                <p unselectable="on">Select any portion of the following blue text</p>
                <p id="p1" style="color= #3366CC">My favorite Web site. Don't forget to click the button! createlink</p>
                </td>
             </tr>
            </table>
    </table>
</body>
```

**maor.css**

```
body {}
p {}
td {}
h1 { color: #f5c391; font-weight: normal; font-size: 20px; font-family: verdana, serif; margin-bottom: 0.2em }
h2 { color: #eaeaea; font-weight: normal; font-size: 16px; margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0 }
form { margin-top: 0px }
a:link { font-weight:bold; color:#36f; text-decoration:none; }
a:visited { font-weight:bold; color:silver; text-decoration:none; }
a:focus { font-weight:bold; color:#d4d4d4; text-decoration:underline; }
a:hover { font-weight:bold; color:#c0c0c0; text-decoration:none; }
a:active { font-weight:bold; color:lime; text-decoration:underline; }
textarea, input { font-size: 8pt }
select, option { font-size: 9pt }
td { color: #333; font-size: 9pt; font-family: verdana, sans-serif }
td.FormControl   { color: #ffe78b; font-size: small; padding-top: 5px; padding-bottom: 5px; border-right: 1px solid #5dafb0; border-bottom: 1px solid #5dafb0 }
td.FormControlrechts   { color: #a88664; font-size: 8pt; text-align: right; padding-top: 5px; padding-bottom: 5px; border-top: #5dafb0; border-right: #5dafb0; border-bottom: 1px solid #5dafb0; border-left: #5dafb0 }
.class { }
```

Comment: Danke schön moskito. A very complete answer. I will try it right away.

Comment: "I do not know what you want to do" - I don't want to display a full HTML page. I want to let the user push some buttons to enter some basic HTML items (links, tables, formatted text) and see the code that TWebBrowser generates for these items. Later, the user should be able to load the HTML code that he generated previously (again, not a complete HTML page).

Comment: I think your code shows the same problem I described: it will alter the link you enter. I paste here again the link to the ORIGINAL problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39745849/how-stop-twebbrowser-from-adding-file-in-front-of-my-links?noredirect=1#comment66824665_39745849

Comment: I don't understand all your screenshot. The label you highlight in green, what does it show? Why is a full path? Can you post the entire code, or better, upload the whole project?

Comment: @Silvester : It is the full code. Place 5 Buttons on the Form One TMemo One TwebBrowser and test it.

Comment: @Silvester : `Why is a full path?` I want to show it's possible with a long path !! `Doc.execCommand('createlink', false,'bearbeiten3.html');` It is only the name **bearbeiten3.html** needed and it will find the file no matter how long the path is !! (of course the file must be in the same Dir or below! **folder1/bearbeiten3.html** will also work.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I got confused by the green label that shows a full path.

Comment: TWebBrowser.document for property does not exist in FMX!

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to display HTML code in Delphi:

```
WebBrowser1.Navigate('about:'+yourHTMLcode);
```