# How to change font in TWebBrowser?

Tags: delphi, font-face, twebbrowser

This question is related to: [Which is the best way to load a string (HTML code) in TWebBrowser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39773033/which-is-the-best-way-to-load-a-string-html-code-in-twebbrowser)

Iam trying to change font in TWebBrowser with doc.body.style.fontFamily but nothing happens. The font is still TimesNewRoman.

```
procedure THTMLEdit.SetHtmlCode(CONST HTMLCode: string);
VAR
   Doc: Variant;
begin
 if NOT Assigned(wbBrowser.Document)
 then wbBrowser.Navigate('about:blank');

 WHILE wbBrowser.ReadyState < READYSTATE_INTERACTIVE
   DO Application.ProcessMessages;

 Doc := wbBrowser.Document;
 Doc.Clear;
 Doc.Write(HTMLCode);
 doc.body.style.fontFamily:='Arial'; <------ won't work
 Doc.DesignMode := 'On';
 Doc.Close;
end;
```

Comment: It depends on the content of the page, how it is styled. There won't be a single solution. Do you have control over the content of the page, or can it be arbitrary?#

Comment: The content is created in TWebBrowser and not imported from a HTML page. The user will enter basic formatting such as bold, bullets, etc.  So, the content has no <head>, <meta>, css, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to let the document be interactive again after you close the document.
e.g.:

```
procedure TForm1.SetHtmlCode(CONST HTMLCode: string);
VAR
   Doc: Variant;
begin
  if NOT Assigned(wbBrowser.Document)
  then wbBrowser.Navigate('about:blank');

  //WHILE wbBrowser.ReadyState < READYSTATE_INTERACTIVE // not really needed
  //DO Application.ProcessMessages;

  Doc := wbBrowser.Document;
  //Doc.Clear; // not needed
  Doc.Write(HTMLCode);
  Doc.Close; 
  Doc.DesignMode := 'On';

  WHILE wbBrowser.ReadyState < READYSTATE_INTERACTIVE
  DO Application.ProcessMessages;

  doc.body.style.fontFamily:='Arial';

  ShowMessage(doc.body.outerHTML); // test it
end;
```

But I think the best way is to handle the `OnDocumentComplete` where you know you have a valid document/body, and set the style or what ever else needed.

Comment: Like a charm. MANY THANKS. You are really good with TWebBrowser.

Comment: I know I should not use ProcessMessages. I am too lazy/in a hurry to implement OnDocumentComplete now. But I promisse I will do it :)

Comment: You are welcome. `TWebBrowser` is processing asynchronously and event driven. switching to `OnDocumentComplete` will eventually make your life easier, and (hopefully) bug free.